# Clicking noise from front wheel

Tags: dodge, noise, wheel-bearing, charger

Vehicle model: DODGE CHARGER SRT8 2008 6.1 318kw

Recent fixes:

- Complete front suspension replacement

Notes:

- TPMS for both rear wheels not working (mechanics did not succeed to replace it correctly, 2 times already)
- Steering shaft need to be replaced (said by couple mechanics)
- Wheel bearings for all wheels will be replaced this week.

After having went through couple mechanics, I did not find out what was causing this strange clicking noise coming randomly from my front left wheel.

It's about 1 000 miles already, since first time, it get's more often.
It start making that clicking noise when you drive more than couple minutes after idle start.

It happens even when you are not breaking. When I drive and start to making a gentle turn to left side for more then 5 degrees, that noise is gone.

The faster I drive, the faster it clicks.

Here is a video: [CLICKING NOISE FROM FRONT LEFT WHEEL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZ7jHExL8bI&feature=youtu.be)

**when a vehicle is jacked up, or lifted by a crane**, and wheels are rotating, no sound is coming out, only when the wheels are on the ground

Any tips will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you jack up the front end and turn the wheel, can you still hear it?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - No, it does not make any sounds when the wheel is rotating in the air. Only if the wheel is on the ground and rotating (moving)

Comment: Are you sure it's the wheel action which is causing the noise? Have you checked the driveline (u-joints)?

Comment: What has been done by the other mechanics?  Any new parts?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - you mean **Steering shaft** ? Not so long time ago, some mechanic told me that it should be replaced. Do you think it could be caused by that U-joint ?

Comment: @cano - complete front suspension replaced (control arms, lower balls, joints, links, etc...)

Comment: No, I mean the drive line ... the part which goes from the transmission to the rear differential. It's amazing how noises under the car can transfer without you even realizing it. If the bearings in a u-joint go dry, they can click like what you're experiencing.

Comment: You could take a look at the hardware for the brake pads. Look at the clips the pads ride on. Make sure they are on properly.

Comment: Make, model, year of the car ? (i.e.  is it equipped with tire pressure sensors?I've seen those get loose inside tire, make weird noises...)

Comment: Since the noise does not happen when the suspension is extended, have you checked the wheel well to verify nothing is hitting the tire/wheel? A piece of trim, or something similar, could be rubbing.

Answer (score 2):

When you have Mag wheels I believe you have to re-torque them every couple of months or so. If I remember correctly it has to do with the different rates of expansion and contraction between the magnesium alloy wheels and the steel bolts and over time they work themselves loose.

Comment: This is very a very important note to follow. It was a hilarious to understand that I was rolling about 150 - 200 km/h with those wheels not well tightened

Comment: You are very lucky to be alive. Losing a front wheel at that speed would result in multiple vehicle rolls killing you, your passengers and anybody that you hit, Make sure that the bolts are properly seated and torqued.

Comment: I guess, there is no need to mention what a scandal I did to those guys who let me go on the road like that. That's again, a new crazy creepy story about the car mechanics in Paris...

Answer (score 1):

I'd try swapping the wheel around for another one to see if the noise is still there. The noise could be where the wheel is moving slightly as it contacts the disk, in which case a slight dab of grease between wheel and disk may help.

Another possibility if its not the suspension or a CV joint etc is that the rim is cracked. Again swapping the wheel for another may help narrow things down.

Comment: thank you, that's an intelligent approach to check the things out before searching further. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: Wait.... Are you saying to use grease on the brake disc...? Or do you mean on the brake disc hat where it contacts the wheel? I truely hope you meant the hats.
If it is to do with the hats, surely the idea would be to wire brush, sand and THEN grease to allow a flush fitment? Either way, if you do use grease there, use a thin amount so that it doesn't flick onto the discs, which would be BAD.

Comment: @yollooool... please read what I suggested fully.

Comment: Nope, not helping. All you said is 'disk' throughout that from where I'm looking. The rim/wheel should not be touching anything except the wheelnuts/bolts and the hats of the rotors; What could the wheel possibly be touching? I suspect by 'disk', you're meaning brake disc, which is what most people would be thinking...

Comment: The studs pass through the disc. The wheel then fits over the studs and this is where the back of the wheel contacts the disc. A slight smear of grease between wheel and disc is normal on those areas as it helps prevent the knocking/clicking that can sometimes occur between the dissimilar metals of disc and wheel. So you would remove the wheel then rub a little grease were the wheel contacts the disc. Be careful not to get grease on the discs braking/friction surface.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that both front wheel bolts weren't strongly tightened. That's all... Somehow they lose the tightness

Comment: Were the wheels Mags?

Comment: @resident_heretic - yeah, five of them on both sides